# App exits when I hit "search icon" on android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, searchview

When I run app it work perfectly fine but when I hit Search icon for searching whole appexits without any error on Event log window.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
List<Dataitem> lstdata;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lstdata = new ArrayList<>();

    lstdata.add(new Dataitem(R.drawable.andhra,"Andhra Pradesh"));
    lstdata.add(new Dataitem(R.drawable.arunachal,"Arunachal Pradesh"));
    lstdata.add(new Dataitem(R.drawable.assam,"Assam"));
    lstdata.add(new Dataitem(R.drawable.bihar,"Bihar"));
```

ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);

```
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,R.layout.itemrow,lstdata);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("Country",lstdata.get(position).countryname);
            intent.putExtra("Flag",lstdata.get(position).residthumbnail);

            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

            return false;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

}

//Cutsom_Adapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Dataitem> {

Context context;
int layoutresid;
List<Dataitem> data = null;
private Object Activity;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Dataitem> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    this.context = context;
    this.layoutresid = resource;
    this.data = objects;
}

static class dataholder
{
    ImageView ivflag;
    TextView tvcountryname;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {

    dataholder holder = null;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutresid,parent,false);

        holder = new dataholder();
        holder.ivflag = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivcountry);
        holder.tvcountryname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvcountry);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }

    else
    {
        holder = (dataholder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    Dataitem dataitem = data.get(position);
    holder.tvcountryname.setText(dataitem.countryname);
    holder.ivflag.setImageResource(dataitem.residthumbnail);

    return convertView;
}
```

}

//menu_main.xml or search layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Help please

Comment: Please share your layout file and customadapter code.

Comment: I did it check out